# How do I set the packet size (in bytes) when I ping host from another?

Tags: networking, packet, sdn, mininet

I've tried my best to look around www.mininet.org and other walkthroughs and simply can't seem to find the general format syntax for the 'ping' command. The command :

*h1 ping h2*

pings between the hosts *h1* and *h2* with a 64 byte echo packet. How can I change this parameter (packet size)? I would like to experiment with packets of varying sizes, such as 40 bytes, 1000 bytes and so on. I'm guessing there must be an upper limit on this, but not sure what it is.

I've tried using the command

*h1 ping -l 40 h2*

but this is incorrect syntax as per mininet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any available Linux command or program can be run on any virtual host. 
Check manual page of ping.

try:`mininet> h1 ping -c count -s packetsize h2`

```
-s packetsize
```

Specifies  the  number of data bytes to be sent.

```
 -c count
```

Stop after sending count  ECHO_REQUEST  packets.  With  deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the time‐out expires.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Do you know where I can find more details on the syntax?